# Accessing JSON properties

Tags: javascript, json, api, object

I'm using a location API and would like to **access the `adminArea1` value**, so that I can store the country in a JavaScript variable. How would I access that value in this case? I already know how to import this JSON to JavaScript (as an object), so that is no problem. The object is called `locationResults`.

```
{
    "results": [{
        "locations": [{
            "latLng": {
                "lng": -76.329999,
                "lat": 40.0755
            },
            "adminArea4": "Lancaster County",
            "adminArea5Type": "City",
            "adminArea4Type": "County",
            "adminArea5": "Lancaster",
            "street": "Granite Run Drive",
            "adminArea1": "US", //THE VALUE I WANT
            "adminArea3": "PA",
            "type": "s",
            "displayLatLng": {
                "lng": -76.333129,
                "lat": 40.07657
            },
            "linkId": 0,
            "postalCode": "17601",
            "sideOfStreet": "N",
            "dragPoint": false,
            "adminArea1Type": "Country",
            "geocodeQuality": "ADDRESS",
            "geocodeQualityCode": "L1AAA",
            "mapUrl": "http://open.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=Fmjtd|luur2du2n1,bn=o5-9ar2l0&type=map&size=225,160&pois=purple-1,40.0755,-76.329999,0,0|&center=40.0755,-76.329999&zoom=15&rand=-320722776",
            "adminArea3Type": "State"
        }],
        "providedLocation": {
            "latLng": {
                "lng": -76.329999,
                "lat": 40.0755
            }
        }
    }],
    "options": {
        "ignoreLatLngInput": false,
        "maxResults": -1,
        "thumbMaps": true
    },
    "info": {
        "copyright": {
            "text": "© 2014 MapQuest, Inc.",
            "imageUrl": "http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif",
            "imageAltText": "© 2014 MapQuest, Inc."
        },
        "statuscode": 0,
        "messages": []
    }
}
```

Using the following:

```
$.getJSON(reverseGeoRequestURL, function(reverseGeoResult){
    window.country = reverseGeoResult.results[0].adminArea1;
    console.log(window.country);
});
```

Gives the console output "**undefined**".

## Solution

This JSON sure is messy! I figured out how to get to the value:

`locationResults.results[0].locations[0].adminArea1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
locationResults.results[0].adminArea1
```

Assuming you want first one and you have already checked if `locationResults.length > 0`.

You access properties of object in js using either dot operator or bracket operator with property name as string. With property it would be:

```
locationResults.results[0]['adminArea1']
```

Comment: Forgot results property